# Pure Javascript API for Twitter and Google Plus

Tags: javascript, php, twitter, google-plus

Using this code I can share to Facebook using just Javascript and my own UI buttons/links etc.

```
FB.init({
    appId      : 'MyAppId',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.0'
});

//In my .click() method)
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'share',
        href: document.URL,
    }, 
    function(response){
        log(response);
        if (typeof response != 'undefined') {
            alert('Thanks for sharing');
        }
    }
);
```

Do Twitter and Google Plus have something similar? At the moment I'm needing to use their HTML, and therefore their styling. I'd like to be able to style the "share" options I have to match the site I'm working on.

If it isn't possible through just Javascript is it possible using PHP? I'm thinking I could do an Ajax call to share the page if PHP could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ has a [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript) that supports all of their existing API functionality. However Google+ does not allow posting without using their [button and UI](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive). The exceptions being if you want to use [app activities](https://developers.google.com/+/web/app-activities/) or are only going to be used by [Google Apps accounts](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/).

Twitter had a [JavaScript API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome) that they stopped supporting in 2013. To post to Twitter you will have to proxy requests through your own server.